# MongoDB and Artisan Make Migration on Laravel 5 and Lumen

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, lumen

As the title says, is there a way I could use Laravel's Artisan command to generate migration scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you really need to as MongoDB will store whatever attributes your models have set as it is a document store and not a relational database.